# How can I simulate a negative lookup in a regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, alteryx

I have the following regular expression that includes a negative look ahead. Unfortunately the tool that I'm using does not support regular expressions. So I'm wondering if its possible to achieve negative look ahead behaviour without actually using one.

Here is my regular expression:

```
(?<![ABCDEQ]|\[|\]|\w\w\d)(\d+["+-]?)(?!BE|AQ|N)(?:.*)
```

Here it is working with sample data on Regex101.com:

[see expression on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gU8cV6/1)

I'm using a tool called Alteryx. The documentation indicates that it uses Perl, however, for whatever reason the look ahead does not work.

Comment: So, you can't use regular expressions at all (that's what your question currently says)? Or you just can't use lookaheads? Can you provide sample data and more insight into what you need to do (what language/tool, etc.)?

Comment: I can use regular expressions, but look ahead don't seem to work.

Comment: What are you trying to match here?

Comment: Are you it is the lookahead and not the lookbehind that is not working?

Comment: @choz Please see the regex101 link. I have a lot of sample data there.

Comment: Aren't those working fine? You're trying to match `15+ vwu&ob12Ai18C` out of `C C ^15+ vwu&ob12Ai18C`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I can't be sure, but I suspect that neither one is working.

Comment: @choz regex101 is my test ground. When I try to use it in Alteryx (the tool I'm using) I get the error.

Comment: I hope [THIS](http://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Knowledge-Base/RegEx-Perl-Syntax-Guide/ta-p/1288) might help

Comment: Please define, using examples in your question, of what should match and not match. Showing us a broken regex is not useful with knowing exactly what it should do.

Comment: @Bohemian I'm trying to match horse racing speed figures.  For example, in the following string: C C ^15+ vwu&ob12Ai18C  the 15+ is the figure I'm trying to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alteryx appears to use the Boost library for its regex support, and the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) says lookbehind expressions must have a fixed length.  It's more restrictive than PHP (PCRE), which allows you to use alternation in a lookbehind, as long as each branch is fixed-length.  But that's easy enough to get around: just use multiple lookbehinds:

```
(?<![ABCDEQ])(?<!\[)(?<!\])(?<!\w\w\d)(\d+["+-]?)(?!BE|AQ|N)(?:.*)
```

That regex works for me in a Boost-powered regex tester, where yours doesn't.  I would compress it a little more by putting square brackets inside the character set:

```
(?<![][ABCDEQ])(?<!\w\w\d)(\d+["+-]?)(?!BE|AQ|N)(?:.*)
```

The right bracket is treated as a literal when it's the first character listed, and the left bracket is never special (though some other flavors have different rules).

Here's the updated [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gU8cV6/2).